# How to fetch some specific rows from DB then rest of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name Where pro LIKE '$pro%' AND address ='$add' OR sub_treat LIKE '$pro%' GROUP BY hos_name ORDER BY treat_price $sorting LIMIT $start_from, $limit ";`

I want to fetch these specific row first and then rest of rows from DB. I'm using mySQL in Window.

Comment: have you tried running the query again with different `$start_from` and `$limit` ?

Comment: This is correct query for specific  rows but I want to rest of rows after these rows so How to write in singal query?

Comment: count the amount of rows you got back, set the start_from on that number and update the limit

Comment: but I'm not getting rows sequentially so how can I do this?